# Existential axioms for category theory

Tags: logic, category-theory, foundations

There are some existential axioms in set theory, for example, axiom schema of specification.

It's my understanding that category theory isn't based essentially on set theoretic foundation.

If so, I think there must be some existential axioms for category theory but I couldn't find description anywhere.

Do you know works about this subject?

Comment: Perhaps you can frame your Question more precisely by referring to the object and arrow formulation originating with Eilenberg and MacLane (1945), summarized in [this Plato article on category theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/#1).  Are you asking if we could have an "empty" category, one with neither objects nor arrows?

Comment: Yes, it's one of my question.

Comment: Everything is essentially based on set theory, if one such desires. One just has to know how to do this, and what set theory to use! :-)

Comment: What do you even mean by "axioms for category theory"?  Unlike set theory, category theory doesn't (most of the time) aspire to be a foundation for all of mathematics, so it's not some fundamental theory that you axiomatize.  It is also unclear in what sense you mean that category theory isn't based on set theoretic foundation: the vast majority of category theory that people do is based on the usual set theoretic foundation of mathematics, just like the rest of math.

Comment: Most authors allow [the empty category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+category).  The language of categories was originally intended to unify and compare a number of constructions across various areas of mathematics.  Therefore the original axiomatization of category theory was not offered as a replacement of set theory for practical foundations.  Later authors have explored that possibility in various ways.  You may find [this early MathOverflow Question and its answers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8731/categorical-foundations-without-set-theory) relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but you might be interested in the following: There is a structural, category-theoretical foundational system for mathematics, namely [Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS). As you have speculated, it is indeed the case that in this formal system you have several category-theoretical existential axioms, for example the existence of pull-backs or the existence of a natural-number object. The existence of pullbacks of monomorphisms is an analogue of the separation axiom in set-theory.